# Move up and move down row of a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a one table where user can select multiple rows, and below to the table there is two buttons moveup and move down. when user will click on movebutton, rows should go move up, similar to movedown.

Below is my Jquery code

```
$(".moveUp").live("click", function(){
    var row = $(".selectRow")
    $(row).each(function() {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    });     
});
```

But it is behaving very wrong. Please help me. I am new in jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: live has been deprecated, you should change it to .on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try like this

```
$(".moveUp").on("click", function() {
    var row = $(".selectRow");
    row.each(function() {
        var $this=$(this);
        $this.insertBefore($this.prev());
    });
});
```

there is no need to wrap `row` using `$(  )` again

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to manipulate an array of pure data (store row and selected state), then trigger a 'render' function on the data after it is changed.  IOW, redraw the entire table on each operation.  Typically this is fast, and an advantage is you can separate the logic/data from the visual interface (like MVC style).